# Node.js : EBADF, Bad file descriptor

Tags: node.js, file-descriptor

If I reload my application (from the browser with the reload button) a lots of times like `50 reload/10 seconds` it gives me this error:

```
events.js:45
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: EBADF, Bad file descriptor
```

This seems to me like a bandwidth error or something like that, originally I've got the error when I played with the HTML 5 Audio API, and If I loaded the audio file 10-15 times sequentially then I've got the error, but now I've discovered that I get the error without the Audio API too just by reloading the site a lots of times, also Safari gives me the error much faster than Chrome (WTF?)

I'm using Node.js 0.4.8 with `express` + `jade` and I'm also connected to a MySQL database with the `db-mysql` module.

I can't find any articles on the web about this topic what helps, so pleeease let me know what can cause this error because it's really confusing :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "reload your application" do you mean refresh your app's home page from a browser, or actually stop and restart the node.js server process?  I assume the former, in which case if you can't reliably reproduce this it will be pretty tricky to debug, especially since you don't have a good stack trace to pinpoint the source.  But if you use the express.js `app.error` hook ([docs here](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling)) you'll want to log the error path from the "Bad file descriptor" error, which should hopefully clue you in to whether this is a temporary file that got deleted or what.  In terms of the actual cause, we can only offer guesses since "Bad file descriptor" is a very generic low level error that basically means you are calling an operation on a file descriptor that is no longer in the correct state to handle that operation (like reading a closed file, opening a file that has been deleted, etc).

Answer (score 0):

@CIRK, take a look at this: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1189

it's not a node problem, but a system tuning issue.

edit: or maybe it's related to this error in connect 1.4.3:
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/297

if this is your case, just try to upgrade it

Answer (score 0):

This error may result from using `fs` to save a file whose name is a **number** rather than a **string**. File names must be strings:

Incorrect:

```
const fileName = 12345;
const fileContent = "The great croissant."

fs.writeFileSync(fileName, fileContent);
```

Correct:

```
fs.writeFileSync(`${fileName}`, fileContent);
```

Also correct:

```
const fileName = "12345";
fs.writeFileSync(fileName, fileContent);
```