# W20141104-19:23:53.848(5.5)? (STDERR) Error: EBADF, read - meteor js error

Tags: meteor

I installed meteor v.9 on windows 7. I am getting this error while run the app on server.

Comment: Meteor is designed for Linux and Mac OS, I don't think anyone can help you with errors on Win7

Comment: Meteor does have a windows port.  Issues can be reported to https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview

Comment: Meteor 1.1 actually has an official Windows installer. I installed it and it gives the same errors

Comment: i don't have any problem by using win7 currently, it depends on docs has been produced from meteor.com how to install it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js : EBADF, Bad file descriptor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688552/node-js-ebadf-bad-file-descriptor)

Answer (score 0):

@user3470138, short version.  Don't use windows to run the server.  It's not your fault.  Windows is great for what it does.  It is not an internet server OS.

If you're mostly a developer, check out [Virtualbox and you can install Ubuntu or Linux Mint yourself](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=install%20ubuntu%20on%20virtualbox%20windows).

If you're into devops, [check out docker and setup a server that way](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=install+docker+on+windows).